# Convert a map to a flatter structure in java 8 streams

Tags: java, dictionary, recursion, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
private Map<String, Object> flatten(Map<String, Object> source) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    source.forEach((k, v) -> {
        if (v instanceof Map) {
            Map<String, Object> subMap = flatten((Map<String, Object>) v);
            for (String subkey : subMap.keySet()) {
                result.put(k + "." + subkey, subMap.get(subkey));
            }
        } else result.put(k, v);
    });

    return result;
}
```

The above code flattens a given Map

```
Ex: 
{
  "hello": {
    "hi": {
      "hola": 1
    }
  }
}

to 
{
  "hello.hi.hola": 1
}
```

I would like to use Java8 streams and implement the same logic, How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: It works fine, But I am trying to implement with Java 8 streams.

Comment: ...to what end?

Comment: Why? What do streams give you that this does not?

Comment: Nothing, I am just trying, how this can be implemented with streams API, but I am not able to.

Comment: There's not much you _can_ use streams to redo here.

Comment: If your code works, you should ask this question at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to post something similar to [@John Bollinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51679674/1553851). Instead I'll offer a somewhat cleaner version using [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
static Map<String, Object> flatten(Map<?, ?> map) {
    return flatten("", map)
            .mapKeys(k -> k.substring(1))
            .toMap();
}

static EntryStream<String, Object> flatten(String key, Object value) {
    if (value instanceof Map) {
        return EntryStream.of((Map<?, ?>)value)
                .flatMapKeyValue((k, v) -> flatten(key + "." + k, v))
                .chain(EntryStream::of);
    } else {
        return EntryStream.of(key, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the Stream API has not been designed to go with the recursion well. There are not much possibilities to "enhance" your solution using Stream API nor refactor. From the definition of Stream API from its [package info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) is obvious that their usage has to be *non-interfering*, *stateless* and without *side-effects* - thus I can't imagine how you would achieve this using this API.

I find the only possible usage amending the inner block of the `if-condition` which brings no real benefit:

```
if (v instanceof Map) {
    Map<String, Object> subMap = flatten((Map<String, Object>) v);
    subMap.keySet().stream().forEach(subkey -> result.put(k + "." + subkey, subMap.get(subkey)));
} else result.put(k, v);
```

Answer (score 1):

The task you present is not well suited to implementation via streams.  What you already have is concise and clean.  Recursion is a particular problem because lambdas cannot refer to themselves or directly recurse.

However, you don't have to express stream operations in terms of lambdas.  You can express them in terms of instances of ordinary classes, too, and such instances *can* recurse.  Thus, you might rewrite your `flatten()` method like so:

```
private Map<String, Object> flatten(Map<String, Object> source) {
    Function<Entry<?, ?>, Stream<Entry<String, Object>>> flattener
            = new Function<Entry<?, ?>, Stream<Entry<String, Object>>>() {
        public Stream<Entry<String, Object>> apply(Entry<?, ?> e) {
            String k = e.getKey().toString();
            Object v = e.getValue();

            if (v instanceof Map) {
                return ((Map<?, ?>) v).entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .flatMap(this)
                        .map(n -> new SimpleEntry<>(k + "." + n.getKey(), n.getValue()));
            } else {
                return Stream.of(new SimpleEntry<>(k, v));
            }
        }
    };

    return source.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .flatMap(flattener)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
}
```

The main body of that, at the end, is a pretty simple stream pipeline.  The magic happens in the `flatMap()` step, with the provided flattening `Function`.  It, too, is written in terms of stream operations, and it recurses by passing itself to its own invocation of `Stream.flatMap()`.

But I cannot imagine why anyone would prefer this mess to the code you started with.

Comment: Must be fun debugging it :)